# Waterline in SailsJS doesn't seem to catch unique constraint

Tags: php, mongodb, validation, sails.js, waterline

In SailsJS, when I have an attribute on a model like:

```
email: { type: 'email',  unique: true}
```

For some reason, Waterline doesn't catch duplicates, but of course Mongo does.  It throws a Mongo error, but Waterline never catches it with WLValidationError.

Anyone having this error?  I can't seem to get WLValidationError to work.

Thanks

Comment: How should waterline know of all values? Imagine you have more than one instance running... You need to catch those errors and react accordingly.

Comment: I assumed that if mongo responded with an error, Waterline would catch that and surface the error in a graceful way.  It seems to do exactly that with other database level errors.  Instead, on duplicate key, it just returns the mongo error.  I assumed since waterline allows a "Unique" property on a field when defining the model, that it would know how to handle uniqueness.  It seems like an incomplete feature.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem too, to overcome I added this to the User model.  I do not like this implementation, but it worked for me when nothing else did.

```
beforeCreate: function(values, cb) {
    User.findOne({email : values.email}, function(err, user){
        if(user){
            return cb('E-mail address already existis');
        } else {
            cb();
        }
    });
}
```

Docs here:

https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline#lifecycle-callbacks